# Why does continue; statement freeze browser?

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration

I'm making a small script that will iterate the numbers and skip the number 5. I want to achieve this with `continue;` statement/label.

Here is my code:

```
<p id="test"></p>

<script>

var i, text;

text = "";
i = 0;

for (;i<8;) {
    if (i === 5) {continue;} 
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    i++;
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;

</script>
```

I'm failing to see any typo error, but coding for more than 12 hours now, maybe I'm overseeing something obvious. If so, I apologize.

This works when I want to stop at number 5 using `break;` statement.

```
<p id="test"></p>

<script>

var i, text;

i = 0;
text = "";

for (;i<8;) {
    if (i === 5) {break;}
    text += "The number is " + i "<br>";
    i++;
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;

</script>
```

Comment: you need to increment i before calling continue otherwise it will get into loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (i === 5) {continue;}
```

will never allow the control to go ahead and increment the `i`. Thus, it'll always go back when `i` becomes five.

**Solution:**

```
if (i === 5) {
    i++; // Increament `i` first
    continue;
}
```

OR, using `for` third argument.

```
for (; i<8; i++) {
            ^^^    // Increment `i` for each iteration
```

---

One more simple thing can be done using `if` condition.

```
for (; i < 8; i++) {

    // If i is not 5, then only append to the string.
    if (i !== 5) {
        text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested and works.. so continue stops before iterator logic. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Update: Interesting thing happens with for `(;i<8;i++) {
 if (i === 3) {continue;} 
 text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
 i++;
}`

Comment: @super11 You've to remove the last `i++` when you're using the same in `for` statement.

Comment: I know now. Regarding the "Update" part it removes the second number, so output is: The number is 0
The number is 2
The number is 4
The number is 6

Comment: I know mate, you didn't understand. I'm saying when I leave `i++` and use `for(;i<8;i+++){continue}` it outputs this: https://jsfiddle.net/3ecp4sh6/ which is interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

This is causing an infinite loop as your value is never being incremented. `continue` will move onto the next iteration, however since you haven't defined a statement to increment your value, this never occurs.

Consider refactoring your loop as follows as opposed to performing your incrementation within the body of the loop:

```
<script> 
    var text = "";
    // This is the most common approach to defining a for-loop as it handles defining
    // your iterator, defining a stop condition and handles how to increment your value
    // after each iteration
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (i === 5) {break;}
        text += "The number is " + i "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (i === 5) {continue;}
```

When `i` is 5 it never gets a chance again to reach `i++`. So, `i` will ever be 5 and you will never exit the loop.